# Finding the largest divider of big number without fractions

Tags: algorithms, factoring

Let's say I have a list of random numbers, all very big;

$$A: 1304810398401344441324$$

$$B: 5641893748137481374813764$$

$$C: 33322299992418948194899999$$

etc..

I want to be able to divide each and every number with another number, let's call it a divider, which will be unique for each number, however, I would like to find the biggest "divider" which will divide a number without leaving fractions.

How can I go about doing this in an efficient manner without trying every possible combination of random numbers???

to make it less complicated I'm making the "divider" at least $\frac 13$ as long as the number that's being divided by it.

Is this possible at all?

Thanks.

Comment: Look up [integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization)

Comment: Find the prime factorization of each number, and then find what factors (and to what power) they all have in common. P.s. the three numbers you just listed there do not share any common divisor.

Comment: What you call "dividers" are usually called "divisors", Of course, any number is its own larger divisor. If I understand the question correct, you are looking for how to determine the "largest proper divisor" of a given integer. (Here proper means that you exclude the given nubmer itself.)

Comment: Oh I think I made it unclear, I meant each number will have a unique divisor, which will make it as small as possible.

Comment: @Travis yes that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: If you tell us why you want to know it's possible that there are better ways to get what you want. For example, if those big numbers are just made up rather than randomly generated, you could make them up by multiplying together some big primes, so you'd know the divisors in advance. (Of course that won't help if the numbers are given to you somehow.)

Comment: The numbers are not truly random, but are not possible to predict, so random in this particular application.

What I'm trying to do is find the smallest two numbers to multiply to get the resulting big number.

However the two numbers to multiply must not have any fractions, or if they do nothing larger than 6 decimal places ( which might not be possible to predict)

Comment: Why don't you use the fact that the largest number that divides any $n$ without factions is $n$ itself and be done with this?

Comment: Why don't you use the fact that the largest "other" number that divides any $n$ without fractions is $n/2$ and be done with this?  Why isn't this problem trivial?

Answer (score 2):

A thorough answer to your question is impossible on this site. Whether one can factor large numbers efficiently is an important open question. If you could do it much of the security on the internet would be at risk.

Your examples aren't particularly large for fast computers using the most efficient algorithms known. Wolfram alpha does the first one pretty much instantaneously, yielding
$$
1304810398401344441324 = 2^2×47×6940480842560342773
$$
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+1304810398401344441324

You can start reading at

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Answer (score -1):

Just divide each $n$ by $n$ itself (or $n/2)$.  That trivially satisfies all your stated requirements.

Comment: unfortunately not, the number itself must be reduced in size as an outcome. And not to 1, 5000 to 50*100 is an example for what I need to acheive.

Comment: The question does say "another number" to be fair; implying distinctness.

Comment: OK.  Then just divide $n$ by $n/2$.  Somehow I have a feeling the OP simply hasn't stated the *true* question at hand.